# iterate json array, split and then display in collections of 5 at a time (Laravel, Ajax, Carbon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

As a newbie developer its taken me a while of searching high and low before deciding to post for help, i dont quite fully understand the right syntax phrases to search for i guess so im not finding the right solution.

In a basic explaination:  Im using laravel and Carbon to display dates for the next 60 days from now, Carbon returns the dates just fine and laravel returns the response in a json format something like this:

```
  0: "Tuesday 10th May 2016 "
  1: "Wednesday 11th May 2016"
  2: "Thursday 12th May 2016"
```

And so on.... So in my html i have a div that contains 5 results, However i need to be able to use something like a jQuery onclick function to loadMore results from the json array maybe using splice.

Laravel has the pagination option but it doesnt work on arrays and ive tried virtually everything i can find online to try and get a way to split the array of 60 days into chunks of 5 so when using an onLoad function, the html will be swopped out with the new 5 results.

here is my current onLoad function:

```
    $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: '/dates',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".newdates").html('').append(data);
    }
});
```

and ive also tried the following, The only issue here is that is loads the same 3 spliced results as i need some kind of pagination way or similar to how jquery DataTables works.

```
    $.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: '/dates',
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.slice(0,3), function(i, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    }
});
```

My hoped for outcome would be!

In the html view:

```
Day 1
Day 2
Day 3
Day 4
Day 5
```

(Load More)  <-- Onclick hide the current 5 and show the next 5 available dates.

```
First 5 days are now hidden from the view
Day 6
Day 7
Day 8
Day 9
Day 10
```

And the same Load More function will be available agai

Hope i can find a workaround, Thanks for your time its much apprecaited, Im sure i will get there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to paginate only on the client side, you can save that data in a variable so you don't have to fetch the data again. Besides, you can create a function to paginate and always call it when needed. You should search for a plugin that already deals with pagination (unfortunately I haven't used only client side pagination, so I don't know any up to date plugin).

```js
var myData = {};
var pageNumber = 1;
var ITENS_PER_PAGE = 3;

$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: '/dates',
    success: function(data) {
        myData = data;
        console.log(paginate(myData, pageNumber, ITENS_PER_PAGE));
    }
});

function paginate(data, pageNumber, itensPerPage) {
  return data.slice((pageNumber - 1) * itensPerPage, itensPerPage);
}

function loadMore() {
  pageNumber++;
  console.log(paginate(myData, pageNumber, ITENS_PER_PAGE));
}
```

Comment: console.log spins an error of:  TypeError: data.slice is not a function and then Array [ ] is empty.  I have had to place the hold code snippet into the loadMore function its self as that is whats called using the onclick method.